# Avoid Symfony to override parameters between bundles

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

I'm using YML parameters inside each bundle to use them as data fixtures as follows:

*AppBundle\Resources\config\datafixtures.yml*

```
parameters:
    datafixtures:
        defaultusers:
            0:
                name: john
                email: john@company1.lol
            1:
                name: steve
                email: steve@company1.lol
```

*GeolocationBundle\Resources\config\datafixtures.yml*

```
parameters:
    datafixtures:
        cities:
            0:
                external_service_area: Cantabria
                company_area: Santander
            1:
                external_service_area: Gipuzkoa
                company_area: San Sebastian
```

The problem comes when I import the files in the app *config.yml* file.

```
imports:
    - { resource: '@AppBundle/Resources/config/datafixtures.yml' }
    - { resource: '@GeolocationBundle/Resources/config/datafixtures.yml' }
```

Instead of merging the trees, it overrides them. Is there a way to make them merge?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681885/load-different-data-fixtures-depending-on-configuration-in-symfony-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bassically the tree form makes them override each other, so the best way to avoid it is to define each node with a single complete name:

*AppBundle\Resources\config\datafixtures.yml*

```
parameters:
    datafixtures.defaultusers:
```

*GeolocationBundle\Resources\config\datafixtures.yml*

```
parameters:
    datafixtures.cities:
```